# PHP : link not returning image(s)

Tags: php, image, hyperlink

I have an interesting little situation here.

I fetch image names from a database table; hence, I use the name column, which, in turn, goes into the file system to fetch the image, or icon, that corresponds with a particular row.

I have noticed that, for a db row that has a name such as **"Rosé Wines"**; because of the **"é"** (if not, the "`") inside of the string, the image is not returned.

How do I fix this problem?

All the other images, as long as they don't have something like **a "`"** in the string load just fine.

Comment: I think you forgot your code. On topic: urlencode your picture names.

Comment: Sounds like a character encoding issue. It might well be that the encoding in the database and/or scripting engine is _different_ to the one used in the local file system which obviously will lead to issues. URL encoding might be missing if you try to reference those images using html links. We cannot really help here, since you did not post any of the code that leads to the problem. You will have to start debugging yourself and check all intermediate points in your script.

Comment: You should urlencode the filenames before passing them to the database.